# NSWindow child window close on parent click

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit

I need to implement a custom popover (cannot use `NSPopover`). Its all working fine, but I also need to implement that the popover closes itself when the user clicks somewhere in the parent window.

What's the best way to implement this, resp. how could this be implemented without subclassing the parent window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the popover key window when showing it, and use `NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification` (or the delegate method) to close when it resigns that status (which happens when user makes some other window active). Closing whenever the parent window is closed is also a good idea (`NSWindowWillCloseNotification`).

Comment: `NSWindowDidResignMainNotification` won't work, because the window won't resign main if the parent is clicked.

Comment: @ErikAigner Sorry, it's key, not main. That's how my popover does it. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Also tried it with key (thought you might mean key instead), but didn't work :(

Comment: I implemented it overriding `NSWindow`s `sendEvent:` before and I think I'll go back to that since the parent window style should remain as key when a popover is active. This is also the default `NSPopover` behavior and I want to match the behavior as closely as possible.

Comment: In case this helps anyone, windowDidResignKey (and windowDidBecomeKey) will not be sent if [canBecomeKeyWindow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419543-canbecomekeywindow?language=objc) is false.